# Как работать со вспышкой в андроид начиная с 4-ой версии?

Tags: android

Пытаюсь работать со вспышкой камеры. При импорте класса:

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

пишет, что он *deprecated*.

Как работать со вспышкой в андроид начиная с 4-ой версии и выше?

Answer (score 0):

Camera2 , используй этот класс.